# Where to define extern declared variables in view of compiling a library

Tags: c, static-libraries, extern

I'm working on an embedded project but my question is more about general best practices.

I'm writing a source file that will operate a peripheral on a microcontroller and in the header file I declared two buffers that are needed for it to work properly.

```
extern volatile struct my_buffer peripheral_Tx_Buffer;
extern volatile struct my_buffer peripheral_Rx_Buffer;
```

For a bit of context they are `volatile` because they are supposed to work inside an ISR and the `struct my_buffer` is a simple circular buffer consisting of an array, a reading and a writing head.

For now everything's ok but I'm planning to compile it into a library so I can give the source code to others without disclosing everything. Now, this isn't the most clever or revolutionary code ever written but I prefer to keep certain things to myself. Anyway, that's not the point!

What I want to know is WHERE to define the two buffers. They are global so that the user can process the incoming data stored in `peripheral_Rx_Buffer` and write to the peripheral through the `peripheral_Tx_Buffer`.

Since they are declared in the public header (so their existence is known) should I leave to the end user (which can be the future me) the duty to define them every time the library is used for other projects? For example define them in the main portion of the program, i.e. where `main()` resides.

Or it's better for me to define them in the `pheripheral.c` that will be compiled in the library so that I'm sure they will actually exists (removing one potential source of errors)?

How should I communicate what to do? What kind of documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to encapsulate both buffers - put them static in source file. Instead of exposing buffers you should rather write in header file public API to access them (read, write, etc.). You can use doxygen do document exposed functions for other developers. In this way you will be sure that both buffers exists only once in the code, and anybody can access them by exposed API.

Moreover, you can limit what end user can do with both buffers, by writting access functions in a way that you want.